# Javascript - passing value to a callback

Tags: javascript

I have this JS code. I need to pass the loadItemUrl value to the callback function off loadStruct method. The loadStruct is a function of a JS framework that we're using.

In this example is the loadItemUrl value undefined in the inner scope of the callback function.

```
Form.prototype.Create = function (loadItemUrl) {

     var dhxForm = new dhtmlXForm(this.divId);

     dhxForm.loadStruct(this.url, function () {

        if (loadItemUrl)
            this.load(loadItemUrl);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `loadItemUrl` is `undefined` then it is because you aren't passing a defined value to `Form.Create` when you call it.

The callback function is defined in the scope of the Create function, so it will have access to any variables that exist there.

Answer (score 1):

> In this example is the loadItemUrl value undefined in the inner scope of the callback function.

I'm assuming that's your question, in which case the answer is **no**.  The *loadItemUrl* argument is scoped as a local variable to the outer function block and is therefore accessible from the inner function block.

The code you have should work fine, assuming the *loadItemUrl* argument is correctly passed to the *Form.prototype.Create* function.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `loadItemUrl` will be accessible to the callback function, which will, in this case, form a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). However, in the execution context of the anonymous callback function, the value of `this` is entirely determined by the implementation of `loadStruct`. One way to solve it is to take further advantage of the closure capabilities of JS and do

```
var dhxForm = new dhtmlXForm(this.divId);
var self = this;

dhxForm.loadStruct(this.url, function () {

    if (loadItemUrl)
        self.load(loadItemUrl);
});
```

That would make sure that `load` is invoked on the correct object.